# fail2ban banned my IP but I still can SSH

Tags: 16.04, ssh, fail2ban

Hi I am trying to use fail2ban to protect my server's SSH.

I can see my ip is banned from:

`sudo fail2ban-client status sshd`

But I can still ssh in the machine through the same ip. Why the fail2ban is not working? BTW I have change the SSH port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`, change the `sshd` port from `ssh` to `YOUR_SSH_PORT`.

This answer has more details: https://serverfault.com/a/382859/406146